# debug.keystore, Invalid keystore format Flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

The error is:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\tavo_\.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Due to this error I thought the problem was my debug.keystore so I created a new one with the command

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

But this didn't fix the problem. It's also worth knowing that this problem (I think at least) started when I was trying to get the SHA certificate fingerprints for my project in firebase. However the command:

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

did not work at first, it gave me another command as solution, I ran it and it worked, I got the SHA certificate and I continued with the development of the app without running the app on an android emulator or a physical device because I was coding the auth logic.

I think the cause of this problem might be related to the command I ran (which I have not saved nor remember) but I have no idea how to solve it.

This problem is presented in all my flutter apps, the ones I already had created and the ones I create.

This is my log for `flutter doctor -v`. I'm putting this just in case, because I don't think the problem is with the flutter SDK.

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1110], locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at C:\Flutter\flutter_windows_1.22.6-stable\flutter
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (6 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\tavo_\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Users\tavo_\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-C\ch-0\203.7148.57
    • Flutter plugin version 59.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 203.8292

[√] VS Code (version 1.58.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\tavo_\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.25.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Edge (web) • edge • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 92.0.902.67

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the key generate from

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

And put it in:

```
"C:\Users\tavo_\.android\debug.keystore"
```

Comment: the command shows an existing key, the other one is the one that can create a new key, however as I wrote, creating a new key and placing it inside "C:\Users\tavo_\.android\debug.keystore" did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You might have changed the format for the debug.keystore

if that's the case you should have a backup automatically created by keytool in at `.android/debug.keystore.old`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Resolved by removing the keystore `.android/debug.keystore` and run the application again.